# View with partial view that also has IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application for college football fightsongs.  I want to display a single teams's details like school name, mascot, conference, etc... but also have a partial view on the same page where the partial view loops through the teams's fight songs.  I was able to achieve this with using an IEnumerable for the fight songs and Viewbag for the data, but I don't believe that is best practices.

I want my code to be as lean as possible and having 30 Viewbags in my view is probably not the best way to do it.

My code blows up on `@Html.Partial("_FightSongDetails")`

Here is the error:

> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type 'SportSongs.Models.ViewModels.ConferenceTeamViewModel', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SportSongs.Models.ViewModels.ConferenceTeamViewModel]'.

I believe this is saying my main view needs to have an IEnumerable of ConferenceTeamViewModel but then how do I pull data in without putting the entire page in a foreach loop?

ConferenceTeamViewModel is just my viewmodel with team, conference, and fightsong data.

My current Details Action is:

```
public ActionResult Details( int id = 0)
        {
            var team = _db.Teams.Find(id);
            var conference = _db.Conferences.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConferenceId == team.ConferenceId);
            if (team == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(new ConferenceTeamViewModel()
            {
                Teams = team,
                Conference = conference
            });
         }
```

My Details View (I am able to pull in the single Model data, just not the fightsongs):

```
@model SportSongs.Models.ViewModels.ConferenceTeamViewModel
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          @Model.Teams.School
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          @Html.Partial("_FightSongDetails")
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is my PartialView:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportSongs.Models.ViewModels.ConferenceTeamViewModel>
<tbody id="fightsongPlaylist">
@foreach (var song in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@song.Fightsong.songname</td>
        <td><a href="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.songurl)" class="playbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><i data-songid="@Url.Content(@song.Fightsong.FightSongId.ToString())" class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - does one team have multiple fight songs?  Or are you wanting to show _one_ team's detail but _other_ team's fight songs?

Comment: It would also be more clear if your variables were named properly - e.g. you have a `Teams` property that seems to only hold one team.

Comment: @DStanley Yes each team can have multiple songs, but the details page will only show one team.  So the view will have a single team's name, mascot, conference, but will have X amount of fightsongs.  Thanks

Comment: But is X _that_ team's song or _all_songs, including other teams?

Comment: One team can have multiple songs.  No two teams share the same song.

Comment: You need to show your model so we can understand what your tring do do. If a team has a collection of songs, then `class Team` should have property `IEnumerable<Song>` in which case you just loop through the songs and display each one - something like `@foreach(var song in Model.Teams.Fightsong) { ...}` but your naming conventions make it impossible to understand your structure

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to show the songs for that team in a partial view.  If that's the case, make the model type for the partial view a collection of *songs*, not the *team*).

Change your partial view to

```
@model IEnumerable<FightSong>
<tbody id="fightsongPlaylist">
@foreach (var song in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@song.songname</td>
        <td><a href="@Url.Content(@song.songurl)" class="playbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><i data-songid="@Url.Content(@song.FightSongId.ToString())" class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

and pass the collection to the sub-view:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          @Html.Partial("_FightSongDetails",model.Teams.FightSongs)
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the model.Fightsongs is not avaialble in that partial call.

Comment: Yes, you should add to ConferenceTeamViewModel a property that contains all the fight songs for the team. In this answer ,that property is called Songs, and the object is FightSong. Sounds like if it's just the song, you could have IEnum<string>.

Comment: @coggicc Try `model.Teams.FightSongs`.  I updated my answer.